# Use fadeout effect on dom element obtained from ajax response using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I call in 5 second interval jquery ajax request to php script, which builds and returns html table. Then I put returned table to div on my webpage. User then clicks on a table row on webpage (this table was obtained from ajax request) and I want to fadeout this row.

How to do this?

```
// put data to prepared div obtained from ajax request
var divid="#tabloidOutput";
function refreshdiv() {
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ 
                url: "data/output.php",
                cache: false
            })
    .done(function(msg) {
    // msg contains <table>...</table>
        $(divid).html(msg);
        setTimeout('refreshdiv()', seconds * 1000);
    })
}

//webpage structure
<body>
<div id="tabloidOutput"></div>
</body>

// row fading out
$( "tr" ).click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to register events on dynamically generated content

```
$('tr').on('click', function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

[**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2t1pckvw/5/)

Answer (score 0):

To fadeOut an element on click (`td` in your case)

```
 $( "#tdname" ).on('click',function() {
      $( this ).fadeOut( "slow" );
    });
```

For more see [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Comment: Won't work on dynamically loaded content. `on` is needed in such a case, as Brian points out.